# Why didn't the Tana'im or Amoa'im write a commentary on Tanach?

Tags: tanach, commentaries, tannaim, amoroim, geonim

To the best of my knowledge the first time we have a verse by verse pshat (ie simple or basic authorial intent meaning) commentary on Tanach is from the Geonic period (even if the commentary is not on each and every verse).

I would like to understand why none of the Tana'im, Amora'im or their schools composed any sort of comprehensive pshat commentary on Tanach.

Comment: Perhaps they did but it wasn't preserved? It's difficult to preserve things when everything is transmitted by heart.

Comment: @Harel it was preserved. We call it "midrash" as RabbiK mentioned

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think midrash is comparable to a commentary. Those are two different types of texts.

Comment: @Harel13 it's certainly a different style commentary from the bottom of the Stone Chumash, but Ohr Hachayim is also different from Ibn Ezra.

Comment: @DoubleAA no, I don't think midrash was ever intended to be commentary in the traditional sense of the word.

Comment: That's circular. What's the traditional sense of the word?

Comment: Also what about the targumim?

Answer (score 5):

They in fact did write commentaries, verse by verse, on Tanach, which are the Midrashim. They were very extensive and each midrash therefore only covered a small part of Tanach.

Rabbi Akiva's school wrote Mechilta D'Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai on Shemot, and Sifra on Vayikra, and Sifrei Devarim.

Rabbi Yishmael's wrote Mechilta D'Rabbi Yishmael on Shemot, and Sifrei Bamidbar.

There is Midrash Rabbah, Sechel Tov, Midrash Tanchuma, Pesikta D'Rav Kahanna, Sefer HaYashar, Tanna Debei Eliyahu and many more.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear, I will update - I'm looking specifically for a 'pshat' commentary, not (mi)derash

Comment: @rikitikitembo much of Midrash is pshat commentary.

Answer (score 2):

If you include the commentary of Philo of Alexandria, AKA Yedidyah HaKohen of Alexandria, you have a fairly comprehensive commentary to the Chumash which comprises both Peshat and Allegorical interpretations.

This understanding is the foundation of the life work of Rabbi Samuel Belkin, z”l of Yeshivah University

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what user Rabbi Kaii brought up about midrashim, Targum Onkelos often weaves interpretation into the translation, making it effectively a pshat commentary on Chumash.